# Create a Github Action's pipeline to automatically build .NET Core console app and create a Release

Tags: c#, .net, github, github-actions, pipeline

I need to create a CI/CD pipeline using Github Actions to build a simple console .NET application. The result should be a yaml-file that I can add to my repository.

**Specs:**

- .NET Core 6 or 7
- The pipline should be triggered by any commit to master-branch.
- After that all NuGet-packages should be restored and a release-build
  should start.
- When everything is built, the artifacts should be packed in a zip archive with `DD.MM.YYYY.zip` name.
- The archive should be posted to Releases page of the GitHub project.

The project should be built for both Mac OS and Windows x64, so there should be 2 archives for both platforms.

Is it possible to do this type of pipeline using GitHub Actions? If so, could you please provide a yaml-example? I'm stuck on the part of creating archives for build artifacts and posting them to Releases page. Please, help

Comment: If you can write some script (such as PowerShell), then creating ZIP packages and automate REST API calls to https://docs.github.com/en/rest/releases/releases couldn't be easier. Then in your YAML file just call that script file.

Comment: I'm almost sure that everything, that I described, can be done using just Github Actions withour Powershell

Comment: My question is whether you want to get things done and more importantly in a consistent way, both on your machine and in a CI system. Using PowerShell script(s) can help you unify that (CI manifest can contain almost nothing), because you can run them reliably everywhere. Otherwise, you are maintaining two pieces of the same thing in two formats (build scripts on your local machine, and CI manifest). Feel free to think differently though, if you prefer to lock yourself up with GitHub Actions.